# How to find the dimension of $Sp\{t_1,..,t_k,b\}$ if $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=a$ has unique solution while $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=b$ doesn't have solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Find the dimension of $Sp\{t_1,..,t_k,b\}$ if $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=a$ has unique solution while $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=b$ doesn't have solutions. $t_1,..,t_k,a,b$ are vectors in the linear space $T$.

From the fact that $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=a$ has unique solution it follows that the set of $t_1...t_k$ is linearly independent. Also $t_1...t_k$ form a subspace to the null space of $T$. This means that $t_1...t_k$ is both linearly independent and spans null space which means that $t_1...t_k$ form a basis so $dim(t_1...t_k)=k$.

Because $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=b$ then $b$ can't be a linear combination of $t_1...t_k$ otherwise that'd be a unique solution $x_1t_1+..+x_kt_k=b$ which contradicts the given.

Therefore $\{t_1...t_k,b\}$ is linearly independent so $Sp\{t_1,..,t_k,b\}=k+1$.

I'm not sure if my proof is good in general and whether I need to prove that $Sp\{t_1,..,t_k,b\}$ spans a linear space.

Comment: Your use of the phrase 'the null space of $T$' in the second paragraph is a bit weird since before $T$ was the vector space, not an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, except from some notational issues. I guess that the letters $Sp$ stand for span, so you cannot say $Sp\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \}$ spans a linear space: the statement is that either $\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \}$ spans a linear space or $Sp \{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \}$ IS a linear space.

Related: you cannot say $\dim(t_1, \ldots, t_k) = k$ but should say $\dim (Sp\{t_1, \ldots, t_k\}) = k$: spaces have dimensions, sets of vectors do not.

Similarly you cannot say $Sp\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \} = k + 1$ but you should write $\dim (Sp\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b\}) = k + 1$: dimensions can be equal to numbers, linear spaces can't.

But this is all notation. Conceptually you got it right!

Comment: And regarding $\{t_1..t_2,b\}$ do I need to prove that it spans a space as well? What is that space?

Comment: It spans a space: every set of vectors spans a space. This space is denoted $Sp\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \}$ exactly because it is the span of $\{t_1, \ldots, t_k, b \}$. There is really not more to say about it.

Comment: ...on the other hand, what is interesting is that you could not find a *shorter* notation for this space. You showed that this space is $k+1$ dimensional and hence could not be written as the span of a smaller number of vectors.